# Compilation problems with django static precompiler

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-static-precompiler

I am trying to compile my scss file and this is the error I have :

> Exception Value: relation "static_precompiler_dependency" does not exist

Here is what is in my html head :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/main.scss"|compile %}">
```

And here in my setting.py :

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/css')
```

I can see the COMPILED folder. But still having that exception error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems you haven't migrated after installing it.

https://github.com/andreyfedoseev/django-static-precompiler/blob/master/static_precompiler/models.py

It has a model called `Dependency`. The model is used for imported `scss` files.

[image]